# Converting printed output of function to a list

Tags: python, list, function, output

I have a function called `game()` which prints out a number.

I need to run this 500 times using

```
for i in range(500):
    game()
```

but I cannot figure out how to convert this output of 500 numbers into a list.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a list, and append the output of `game()` into that list:

```
l = []

for i in range(500):
    l.append(game())
```

Or you can just use [*a list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951) like below:

```
l = [game() for i in range(500)]
```

Note that if your `game()` function doesn't just *return* the value you want to put in a list, but *print* it out.

Then you have to change something like `print(value)` to `return value` in your `game()` function. Otherwise the list `l` will be full of `None`.